# How does AngularJS implement two-way `'='` binding in its directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest, two-way-binding

#### How does AngularJS making bind by reference in its directives?

Sometimes when i pass variable by reference using `'='` in my `directive`, and update the referenced variable in the `parent controller`, it does not get updated instantly, but it gets updated after making `$scope.$digest()`.

what i think is that angular doesn't make reference binding like JS binding, but when the `scope digest` its just update its referenced variables.

i don't know if my theory is right.

what do you think?

Comment: https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/ with events that are outside of angular context like regular element user events (mouse and keyboard events) do not automatically trigger a $apply/$digest so you must trigger them manually.  The triggering of the $apply will cause any watchers to check for new values and fire any watch handlers which are implicitly made with data bindings in the view or explicitly made in the JS.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L49 <-- can see the built in ngClick etc fire the digest

Comment: Theory is incorrect and is too general a way to look at how it all works

Comment: Also to note the `$timeout` and `$http` services automatically trigger $apply after data comes back or the timeout completes so you don't need to manually apply it there.  Can find details of watch and the digest cycle on this page in the docs as well https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AngularJS [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) implements two-way `'='` binding by adding a watcher:

> ```
> var parentValueWatch = function parentValueWatch(parentValue) {
>   if (!compare(parentValue, destination[scopeName])) {
>     // we are out of sync and need to copy
>     if (!compare(parentValue, lastValue)) {
>       // parent changed and it has precedence
>       destination[scopeName] = parentValue;
>     } else {
>       // if the parent can be assigned then do so
>       parentSet(scope, parentValue = destination[scopeName]);
>     }
>   }
>   lastValue = parentValue;
>   return lastValue;
> };
>
> parentValueWatch.$stateful = true;
> if (definition.collection) {
>   removeWatch = scope.$watchCollection(attrs[attrName], parentValueWatch);
> } else {
>   removeWatch = scope.$watch($parse(attrs[attrName], parentValueWatch), null, parentGet.literal);
> }
> removeWatchCollection.push(removeWatch);
> ```
>
> [— GitHib AngularJS compile.js Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L3504)

The watcher checks to see if the parent scope property is out of sync with the isolate scope property and updates as necessary. This means that the isolate scope is only updated after a digest cycle.